# Fast string hash function for a specific table size?

Tags: hash

I tried writing two hashing function and compared it to [MurmurHash64A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash). To my disappointment one was better but maybe 1.5x slower and the other was slightly faster but had more collisions when I truncated the bits to put in my hash table ((Hash64bit^(Hash64bit>>32)) & 0x9FFFFF). Apparently it didn't distribute well.

From memory there was a random number algorithm where I could pick a prime and coprime to get a uniform distribution (it may have been a type of linear feedback shift register algorithm). I was wondering if something exist for hash tables where if I know how many slots I have I can pick numbers for better distribution.

I'm expecting 200K unique words for one table (I'm hoping I can use 1M slots for a 8MB table)  and I have another table that expects around 1K unique words or less (I'm hoping I can use 32K for that). Am I out of luck or is there something I can read or an algorithm I can use to help get a good distribution?

Comment: If I follow it seems you are asking about [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1690541/is-modular-multiplication-under-a-prime-modulus-uniformly-distributed).  No need for coprime.

Comment: I'm wondering why are you going to find a hash function for yourself. The computer programming libraries handle those for you.

Comment: @ModalNest I can't read that I don't know math notation. I'm also unsure how to apply that to a hash function do I run the formula for every letter and sum them up? I know thats wrong because that likely means "ab" and "ba" gives the same results

Comment: If you multiply any number by another number modulo a prime, then it is distributes uniformly.  Per kelalaka's comment there isn't really any reason to code a hash yourself.

Comment: @ModalNest Are you kidding me? No reason? Every library I used gets beat silly by MurmurHash64A and I have a VERY SPECIFIC usecase and usually specific usecases can be optimized

Comment: Use murmurhash then.  Or use Siphash as it's better than murmurhash.  Clearly you shouldn't be trying to code a hash from scratch as you are asking about summing up letters, don't know how to create uniform distribution with primes, and can't read even the most basic math notation (that even I can read). In the future try being VERY SPECIFIC with your question.

Comment: @ModalNest I asked for reading material on how to write a hash. I didn't ask for to write a prng, how to create a uniform distribution on a prng or how to read mathematical notation when I don't know if my recommendation will be a comp sci book or a math book. I asked what should I know if I wanted to write a specific hash or two for two specific usages. I don't even know if there are known ways to optimize hashes for different sizes and use cases

Comment: You didn't ask that in your question, and you mentioned distribution several times.  I never mentioned any PRNG and my link has way more relation to hashing than PRNGs.  You did mention PRNGs though, in your question.  You are going to need to know about math notation, so get cracking on with that.

Comment: They're asking about hashes for hash tables, not cryptographic hashes. Very different set of functions, with very different requirements. EG there's no need for collision resistance against an attacker, just against random inputs (and even then collisions just reduce performance a bit, so you tend to tune the output size to have a few rare collisions based on your actual data set). Multiplication modulo a prime is a rather expensive operation, it'd likely be slower than any of these functions.